# Background Nav bar Image not displaying

Tags: html, css

I have put together a fixed menu bar which appears once scrolled down the page.

http://staging.meadowspetcareservices.co.uk/

I have implemented this, but the customer would like a icon image within the bar. I have tried adding this as a background image within the CSS. But it just isn't showing?

```
nav.nav-header.fixed {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 600;
  background: #9D162E url(/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/meadows-favicon-negative.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 20px center;
  background-size: 56px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0%);
  transform: translateY(0%);
  -webkit-animation: slidedown 2s forwards;
  animation: slidedown 2s forwards;
}

nav.nav-header.fixed.wrap {
  width: 100%!important;    
}

nav.nav-header.fixed ul#menu-primary {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code actually works!

The problem is that this code is applied after your image (*think painted above*)

```
.site-header .genesis-nav-menu {
    background: #9D162E;
}
```

So just remove the background color for the above class and you're good to go!

Comment: yes it works.

Just change `background: #9D162E` to `background: transparent`

Comment: actually just remove it, you're never using it anyway :)

Comment: DOH! Thank you as ever!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
ul#menu-primary{
     background-image: url('wp-content/uploads/2016/03/meadows-favicon-negative.png') !important;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```